# How to set background image, but not behind statusbar in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, image, background

What I've heard there are no real way) to set a background image for a view in swift (tex self.view.background image. After googling around I found this:

```
    var imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame) // set as you want
    var image = UIImage(named: "fade bg3")!
    imageView.image = image
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
```

It worked but the statusbar (with the clock, battery status and network ex) has that background too. Can I prevent this?

**This was the solution**

```
UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))
```

Comment: Create your view like this `UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))`

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders Did I say "hi" or "thanks"? Stack overflow is so stupid, not even allowed to say hi!

Comment: Thanks @VivekMolkar It worked just as I wanted!

Comment: @totoajax: you said "Thanks, Anton!". And [so] is a different kind of site. If you want to get the most out of it, then take the time to go through some of the [help].

Answer (score 1):

Just **Hide** your Status bar for those screens.

Answer (score 1):

You really should implement `prefersStatusBarHidden` on your view controller(s):

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```